# SSIS complains about access rights when path use æøå characters

Tags: ssis

So, I have a SSIS package, which is supposed to write a file to `"..\Prod\OUT\Markedsføringslisten".`

However, SSIS fails, citing access rights:

```
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Flat File Destination failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC020200E.
[Flat File Destination [2]] Error: Cannot open the datafile "..\prod\Out\Markedsføringslisten\AL_Erhverv_Markedsføringslisten_2021_12_06.csv".
[Flat File Destination [2]] Warning: Access is denied.
```

However, If I change the path to:
`"...\Prod\OUT\Markedsfoeringslisten" (ø = oe)` then everything works just fine, meaning that it shouldn't really be an access issue with the subfolder. We need to keep using the same name, however, as other solutions are expecting files from: `"..\Prod\OUT\Markedsføringslisten".`

The package is being build in `SSIS 2017`. An older variant of the package, built in 2013, works just fine. I can't see any immediate difference between the two connections, but feel free to ask for additional information if you feel it could help.

Comment: Are server settings in the correct region?.



Ensure you set the correct [Codepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15) of your Flatfile connection:

Comment: It fails to run even just in Visual Studio. The Locale ID is the same in both packages...

Comment: It [works for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjzy6.png) so let's tease the problem apart a bit more, eh? Is the path literally "..\" in your path or have you simplified the path name? Is the path built dynamically? If so, is it possible that you're losing the true character ø to an ascii  "equivalent"? If you provide a full, explicit path instead of the relative i.e. `C:\ssisdata\prod\Out\Markedsføringslisten\AL_Erhverv_Markedsføringslisten_2021_12_06.csv` does it work?

Comment: The "..\" is just to to shorten the path here.
The full path is:
`\\[sftpserver]\[clientname]\Meeting\ArbejdernesLandsbank\prod\Out\Markedsføringslisten\AL_Erhverv_Markedsføringslisten_2021_12_07.csv`

The path is dynamically built using this expression:
`"\\\\[sftpserver]\\[clientname]\\Meeting\\ArbejdernesLandsbank\\prod\\Out\\Markedsføringslisten\\AL_Erhverv_Markedsføringslisten_"  + REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_STR,50,1252)GETDATE(),1,10),"-","_"), ":","_") + ".csv"`

Exact same expression is used in the 2013 version of the file connection.